# Using LauncherImpl.LAUNCH_MODE_JAR of LauncherImpl.launchApplication method in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have my main class

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String cur_dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    cur_dir += "\\AppTest.jar";
    System.out.println("Jar path="+cur_dir);
    LauncherImpl.launchApplication(cur_dir, LauncherImpl.LAUNCH_MODE_JAR, args);
}
}
```

My Application class

```
public class AppTest extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
           "FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    Parent root=loader.load();
    FXMLDocumentController controller=loader.getController();
    controller.setMyInstance(controller); 
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    //Platform.setImplicitExit(true);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setOnHidden(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
            controller.thread.stop();
        }
    });
    stage.show();
}  
}
```

But it's not working

I followed this [post](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/09/javafx-how-to-easily-implement-application-preloader-2/)

I want to run the latest jar of the application kind of auto update

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you are trying to achieve. You mention auto update, can you clarify please?

Comment: `But it's not working`. Please clarify your problem. Any exception? Please post the stack trace.

Comment: In the preloader i have downloaded the latest jar file of my javafx app and replaced it with old one which was showing me the error **Error in method involking** Once i restart my application it runs with the latest jar.so i am trying launcher implementation to lauch it with latest jar so that i don't need to restart my application